# unable to load resource - 404 Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

```
(function(){
  'use strict';
  angular
    .module('myNinjaApp.user')
    .config(config)

    config.$inject = ['$routeProvider']


  function config($routeProvider)
  {
      $routeProvider
      .when('/user/home',{
        templateUrl:'./views/home.html'
      }).when('/user/directory',{
        templateUrl:'./views/directory.html'
      }).otherwise({
        redirectTo:'/user/home'
      })
  }
})();
```

The files `home.html` and `directory.html` are in the same path but in a folder- views.
But the error is unable to load resource.

Comment: Can you please check while serving your code through server which path is given for the server and also can you provide folder structure hierarchy.

Comment: Mam it was resolved. The path that I was providing was not appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The Path wont include a dot (.) and path will be `templateUrl: 'modules/users/views/home.html'`